# Get SKUs of all bundled product items Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4, magento2.4.6

Get SKUs of all bundled product items Magento 2.4.6

I have a bundled product, let's call the sku BundledProduct.

I have 3 products that can be selected to be bundled with BundledProduct. Let's call the skus AddOn1, AddOn2, and AddOn3.

However, when placing the order, only the AddOn's Names are passed, not the Skus of the add ons. For example, AddOn1's name may be "Warm Gloves" and that gets passed into the admin instead of "AddOn1".

How can I get it to pass the SKU as well of these selected options?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\BundleProductSkus\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function getBundleProductSkus()
    {
        $skus = [];
        $productId = 10;
        try {
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
            if ($product->getTypeId() === \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
                $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
                    $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product),
                    $product
                );
                foreach ($selectionCollection as $option) {
                    $skus[] = $option->getSku();
                }
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return ['error' => $e->getMessage()];
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($skus);
        die();
        return $skus;
    }
}
```

Let me know if any queries.

**Thank you.**